# stepping in python-bitstring 2.2.0

Tags: python, slice, bitstring

**Update:** in python-bitstring 3.0.0 step has the conventional meaning

I am using python [bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/), I have a ConstBitArray loaded from file and I would like to get a slice with a step different from 1.

In a normal list I just would do:

```
s = mylist[start:stop:step]
```

however bitstring has a strange definition for stepping, see:

http://packages.python.org/bitstring/slicing.html#stepping-in-slices

does somebody knows how to do that?

thanks

Comment: ``mylist[start, stop, step]`` gives a ``TypeError`` on my machine (and I've never seen that notation). I presume you mean ``s = mylist[start:stop:step]``?

Comment: thanks! I fixed it. I got confused with slice(start,stop,step)

Comment: Stepping in bitstring has changed to the more conventional meaning in version 3 of the module (which means that your link to the documentation doesn't make sense any more). As of version 3.0.0 it's not well optimised though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite clear in the link you provided that they have chosen to make `mylist[start:stop:step]` syntactic sugar for `mylist[start*step:stop*step]` which unfortunately means you won't be able to use the step in the usual way

You could try something list this as a replacement

```
[mylist[i] for i in range(start,stop,step)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've the same impression, the problem is that using a loop takes forever. I hope somebody has a better solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The behaviour of stepping in the bitstring module changed in version 3 to the more conventional meaning. The answer below refers to bitstring version 2.

---

I'm the author of the bitstring module so might be able to help (or at least explain!) As has been noted the `step` is used to provide a multiplier - this is useful if you want to specify things in terms of bytes or other bit multiples (so `s[a:b:c]` is the same as `s[a*c:b*c]`).

For the behaviour you seem to want there's not such a compact syntax. I'd be interested to know what you need it for - I could never think of a good use for it which is why the other use for step was chosen. The best equivalent I can think of is

```
s = ConstBitArray().join(mylist[i:i+1] for i in range(start, stop, step))
```

This isn't likely to be very fast though.

If all you want to do is check that all or any of the bits are set/unset then you can use something like

```
mylist.all(True, range(start, stop, step))
```

or

```
mylist.any(False, range(start, stop, step))
```

---

Another, probably faster, way to do it is to switch to using the [`bitarray`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) module for the slicing:

```
import bitarray
s = ConstBitArray(bitarray.bitarray(mylist)[start:stop:step])
```

If you main need is just this slicing behaviour you might be better off using bitarray, although it's not available for Python 3 yet.

Comment: thanks Scott, I need to do that because my data are stored as a single bitstring, but are really a bidimensional dataset stored row after row. for this reason I need step to get data by column. I also would like not to load them into RAM, as the size is 12582912x473.

Comment: @Andrea: Getting columns from a file-based array is a bit of a worst case scenario in terms of performance. I really would load them in memory if you want to do much analysis - your bitstring will be about 700MB, so it's big but not unreasonably so. Try `ConstBitArray(12582912*473)` in the Python interpreter - if it can create that then it can hold your data in memory.

Comment: sure, I can hold it in memory, but that is quite slow, it would be nice to have a low-level slicing that would to the work for me and return just the required column.